# Fitting truncnorm distribution with distrplus causes fatal error (R crashes)

Tags: r, fitdistrplus

Here's the code that crashes R for me without any useful error messages. Any ideas? I'm going crazy over here. Thanks,

```
library(fitdistrplus)
library(truncnorm)
set.seed(0)
x = rtruncnorm(n=30, a=0, b=Inf, mean=1, sd=0.45)
my_fit = fitdist(x, "truncnorm", method='mle', fix.arg=list(a=0, b=Inf), 
                 start=list(mean=mean(x), sd=sd(x)))
```

Comment: cool!  can reproduce (R-devel, ubuntu 18.04)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once Ben Bolker identified that truncnorm - not fitdist - is the issue, I decided to simply use a different library. The following code executes just fine for me:

```
library(fitdistrplus)
library(extraDistr)
set.seed(0)
x = rtnorm(n=30, a=0, b=Inf, mean=1, sd=0.45)
my_fit = fitdist(x, "tnorm", method='mle', fix.arg=list(a=0, b=Inf), 
                 start=list(mean=mean(x), sd=sd(x)))
```

Comment: it may also be worth commenting that the MLE for a truncated distribution is always (??) equal to the **observed** truncation point, e.g. if you're fitting a left-truncated normal distribution, then the MLE for `a` (lower bound) is equal to the minimum observed value.

Answer (score 3):

As part of its machinery, `fitdist` calls the specified density function with an `x` argument of `numeric(0)`.  This crashes `dtruncnorm`, which calls C++ code which isn't expecting that ...

```
dtruncnorm(numeric(0))
```

is a way to get to the same crash quicker. I tried to hack my way around this by creating my own `dtruncnorm()` wrapper:

```
dtruncnorm <- function(x,a,b,mean,sd) {
    if (length(x)==0) numeric(0) else truncnorm::dtruncnorm(x, a,b,mean,sd)
}
```

but so far it's still crashing somewhere farther along the line.

It would be community-minded to contact the maintainer of `dtruncnorm`/file an issue [here](https://github.com/olafmersmann/truncnorm) ...

Comment: Bug report submitted. Thanks,