# R crashes when fitting truncated normal distribution

Tags: r, normal-distribution, model-fitting

The following code crashes every time I run it and on two different R versions. I bet I'm doing something wrong (maybe I inadvertently drive the optimization somewhere it can't go?) but I fail to see what. My idea here is to help the MLE the most I can by providing almost good `a`, `mean` and `sd`. As you can see I generate a data sample quite close to the fitting parameters (on purpose).

```
library(truncnorm)
library(fitdistrplus)
fitdist(rtruncnorm(100, a=8, mean=10, sd=1),
        "truncnorm", fix.arg=list(a=8),
        start = list(mean = 10+0.5, sd = 1+0.1))
```

This code crashes (so it quits the R session) with error : "Process R floating point exception at Wed Apr 27 18:03:47 2022" on Linux and "session aborted" on RStudio on Windows. I tried several start parameters for `mean` and `sd` but the result is the same: crash. I use R version 4.0.3.

Comment: Cool, I can reproduce it! (r-devel 2022-04-08 r82134 on Linux) (Even without running `set.seed()`, but note that's best practice for anything that uses random numbers.)

Comment: ugh, I even made the same comment on the duplicate ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr** `fitdistr()` tries to test the distribution function by passing it an `x` value of `numeric(0)`, which crashes `dtruncnorm()`. You could probably write a wrapper that didn't do that.

---

## Debugging sequence

```r
library(truncnorm)
library(fitdistrplus)
set.seed(101)
x <- rtruncnorm(100, a=8, mean=10, sd=1)
debug(fitdist)
fitdist(x,
        distr = "truncnorm", fix.arg=list(a=8),
        start = list(mean = 10+0.5, sd = 1+0.1))
```

Fails in

```r
 resdpq <- testdpqfun(distname, dpq2test, start.arg = arg_startfix$start.arg, 
    fix.arg = arg_startfix$fix.arg, discrete = discrete)
```

More minimal/deeper example:

```r
library(truncnorm)
library(fitdistrplus)
distname <- "truncnorm"
dpq2test <- c("d", "p")
arg_startfix <- list(start.arg = list(mean = 10.5, sd = 1.1), fix.arg = list(
    a = 8))
discrete <- FALSE
debug(fitdistrplus:::testdpqfun)
fitdistrplus:::testdpqfun(distname, dpq2test, start.arg = arg_startfix$start.arg, 
    fix.arg = arg_startfix$fix.arg, discrete = discrete)
```

So we don't even need `x`!

Fails at

```r
res <- rbind(res, test1fun(paste0("d", distr), start.arg, fix.arg))
```

So:

```r
library(truncnorm)
library(fitdistrplus)
arg_startfix <- list(start.arg = list(mean = 10.5, sd = 1.1), fix.arg = list(
    a = 8))
fitdistrplus:::test1fun("dtruncnorm",
   arg_startfix$start.arg, 
    fix.arg = arg_startfix$fix.arg)
```

Which gets us down to

```r
 res0 <- try(do.call(fn, c(list(numeric(0)), start.arg, fix.arg)), 
    silent = TRUE)
```

Which suggests that just

```r
dtruncnorm(numeric(0))
```

is sufficient to trigger the bug.

Comment: This answer to your previous report on this suggests a workaround:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/63432619/2554330 .  A package that ignores a crash-causing bug for 2 years is one to avoid.

Comment: thanks for finding the duplicate!

Comment: Thanks for finding the duplicate, I didn't (I promise I searched). The [issue](https://github.com/olafmersmann/truncnorm/issues/6) has already been reported  2 years ago. Thanks for the excellent research. Although I don't have the solution, I've learned about "debug" which I didn't know !